# Transpose and flip LARGE rasterBrick R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, bigdata, raster

How can one possibly transpose and flip a large rasterbrick (~1TB)? Sample data is found below just for demonstration.  The actual data are flipped.

The code I use in transposing and flipping one layer of the actual file is:

```
a=raster('sample.nc')

d <-  t(flip(a, direction = "y"))

# write it to netcdf file

    writeRaster( d,"d_rotated.nc", overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF", varname="tas", varunit="mm", 
                 longname="daily mean temperature", xname="lon", yname="lat",zname="time",
                 zunit="numeric")
```

How can I implement this on a large file and **speed things up**? I can use CDO or NCO to concatenate the `.nc` files if each transposed layer is written to directory (just in case this is a faster option).

[Sample file can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5o441544dzsigtm/mew.nc?dl=0)

Comment: I think the problem is unlikely to be speed -- the real problem is loading the 1tb raster into memory. I think R is not a great way to solve this problem. I would recommend using GDAL which is much less memory intensive. I believe that the program `gdalmdimtranslate` can be used to both transpose and flip the raster brick: https://gdal.org/programs/gdalmdimtranslate.html

Comment: What format is your data? Is it stored on disk? In which way?

Comment: The data is `.nc` with dims `lon,lat,time`. I am using google cloud, so lots of disk storage.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what `.nc` is.

Comment: `.nc` stands for `NetCDF`

Comment: @qdread can you translate the code above into a `GDAL` solution? I have not used GDAL before. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the version of gdal on my institution's server is too old and does not have `gdalmdimtranslate` so I cannot test out the solution. I might be able to install a newer version. In the meantime if you do figure out a different solution to your problem let us know!

Comment: Revisiting this issue, I think you might find something to answer your question here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2016-February/023990.html